# Why does Windows use UTF-16LE?

Tags: windows, unicode, utf-8

Whereas most of the Unix/POSIX/etc world uses UTF-8 for text representation, Windows uses UTF-16LE.

Why is that? There are multiple folks who say the Windows APIs were written before UTF-8 (and even Unicode as we know it) existed ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292217), [2](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Microsoft-use-UTF-8-on-Windows-10), [3](https://utf8everywhere.org/#faq.naive)), so UTF-16 (or even earlier, UCS-2) was the best they had, and that converting the existing APIs to UTF-8 would be a ridiculous amount of work.

But are there any official sources for these 2 claims? [The official MSDN page for Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode) makes it seem like UTF-16 may even be desirable (though I don't myself agree):

> These functions use UTF-16 (wide character) encoding, which is the most common encoding of Unicode and the one used for native Unicode encoding on Windows operating systems.

Is there any official note (or an engineer who worked on the project) explaining the **reasoning behind choosing UTF-16** and **why Windows would/would not switch to UTF-8**?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Comment: In what way is Linux UTF-8 and Windows UTF-16? Most software I'm aware of on either system lets you select the encoding among a number of options. There are relics of Unicode's 16-bit past scattered all over computing. Check out Java Character APIs and it's `char` type. IMO everything should be UTF-8 and the rest should be deprecated.

Comment: Reference? Check the year of implementation of both encoding (UCS-2 vs UTF-8). Various languages went to UCS-2 (Javascript). C implemented the wide char for this. And it is easy to recognize and split old/vs new. If you check here in SO, there are many people which have mismatched encoding (utf-8, latin-1, "ansi"). Changing from "all 16-bit" (previous Unicode principle), to multiplan created "complex" UTF-16. So not it is better UTF-8, but with UCS-2... not sure what would be best

Comment: This link  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page says
*Microsoft adopted a Unicode encoding (first the now-obsolete UCS-2, which was then Unicode's only encoding), i.e. UTF-16 for all its operating systems from Windows NT onwards, but additionally supports UTF-8 (aka CP_UTF8) since Windows 10 version 1803.* and there is a link to a Microsoft publication but in Japanese.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Raymond Chen actually has an "official" answer—or at least an answer from a Microsoft source (emphasis added):

> Windows adopted Unicode before most other operating systems.[citation needed] As a result, Windows’s solutions to many problems differ from solutions adopted by those who waited for the dust to settle.¹ The most notable example of this is that **Windows used UCS-2** as the Unicode encoding. **This was the encoding recommended by the Unicode Consortium because Unicode 1.0 supported only 65536 characters**.² The Unicode Consortium changed their minds five years later, but **by then it was far too late for Windows, which had already shipped Win32s, Windows NT 3.1, Windows NT 3.5, Windows NT 3.51, and Windows 95, all of which used UCS-2**.³

— [The sad history of Unicode printf-style format specifiers in Visual C++](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190830-00/?p=102823)

In other words, Remy Lebeau and AmigoJack were both right—**Windows adopted Unicode before UTF-8 was recommended** (or even existed?); at the time, UCS-2 was the standard, so that's what Windows chose.

By the time we developed the more efficient (and now more-common) UTF-8 standard, Windows had already shipped several versions, and **it would be immensely impractical (if not impossible) to change**.

<sup>Thanks to everyone who provided answers to this question! Since I was looking for an official source, I'm marking this as the answer (although I'm marking it as community wiki, since it is an amalgamation).</sup>

Answer (score 17):

Windows was one of the first Operating Systems to adopt Unicode.  Back then, there was indeed no UTF-8 yet, and UCS-2 was the most common encoding used for Unicode.  So Windows' initial Unicode support was based on UCS-2.

By the time Unicode outgrew UCS-2, and UTF-8 and UTF-16 became more popular, it was too late for Windows to change over to UTF-8 without breaking tons of existing code <sup>1</sup>, however UTF-16 is backwards compatible with UCS-2, so Microsoft was able to switch to UTF-16 with minimal effort, and little-to-no changes to existing user code.

<sup>1: and now, 20-odd years later, in Windows 10, Microsoft is only just starting to really begin to support UTF-8 **at the Win32 API layer**, but that functionality is still experimental, has to be enabled manually by the user or on a per-application basis via app manifests, and typically requires changes to user code to take advantage of UTF8-enabled APIs rather than UTF16-based APIs.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I find this to be a very pragmatic explanation. I was hoping for *published*/official reasoning from Microsoft explaining the decision, so I will leave this unanswered for now; I have upvoted it, though.

Comment: *"support UTF-**8 at the OS layer**"* - I doubt this is accurate. To the best of my knowledge, UTF-8 support is implemented as a translation layer at the API boundary. The OS still uses UTF-16 internally. Color me surprised if you can prove me wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable I reworded it

Answer (score 1):

By "world" you most likely mean everything: **operating system** (internally used encoding), **executables** (supported encodings), **file formats** (supported encodings), **file systems** (internally used encodings) and more.

*Windows* won't easily switch because i.e. essential file formats such as [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) (used in EXE, DLL and whatnot) have [resource strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/debug/pe-format?redirectedfrom=MSDN#resource-directory-string) that can only cope with codepoints in `WORD`s. The format is already a patch on a patch on a patch, and adding yet another extension to it may be more annoying than just using binary resource blocks and cast them to *UTF-8*.

Since introducing *Unicode* in *Windows* its API was laid out to a `WORD` per character; most *ANSI* versions of each function were only stubs to call the *WIDE* versions of that function. For *UTF-8* it can't be forced and would break with all legacy code - a whole new API would be needed (or a third version for each function). Only few functions are "future ready" because you can tell them in which encoding the text comes (obviously such as [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar)).

[*NTFS* stores every character in `WORD`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Internals), too (thus indirectly supporting *UTF-16*), and I can't see how that will change with just a new version of it - I rather bet a whole new file system will be introduced that obsoletes *NTFS* with at least the new feature of also storing all filenames in *UTF-8*.

Comment: "*a whole new API would be needed (or a third version for each function)*" - not really, and Microsoft has already implemented this in Windows 10, by allowing the user's default codepage to be set to UTF-8, or even just on a per-process basis via manifest.  This allows existing Win32 `A` functions to work with UTF-8 strings now, instead of (or at least in addition to) converting to UTF-16 to call the `W` functions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But there are functions which have no `A` counterpart, like [`ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate).

Comment: Yes, but that is because most such functions were introduced after Microsoft had merged the user editions (XP and earlier) and corporate editions (NT and later) of Windows into one OS and migrated it to being all-Unicode, so there was no longer a need to add new ANSI-based APIs going forward. The `A`/`W` functions are for legacy APIs being carried forward from the pre-Unicode era.

Comment: Aye, but my point was: how to use UTF-8 on those? My guess: it's impossible. Unless they get the `A` counterpart.

Comment: You can't use UTF-8 in the newer UTF16-only APIs, you would have to manually convert between UTF-8 <-> UTF-16 in your own code as needed.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! While it's not an "official" answer from Microsoft, I can understand how *at least some* Windows APIs seem basically impossible to convert to UTF-8 from their signatures alone (though Microsoft's done crazy things before). I upvoted your answer, since I believe it satisfies my internal curiosity, but I'd prefer to leave this question "unanswered" in the hopes that there's an official Microsoft answer for this. Let me know if you think that's inappropriate. Thanks again!