# Delphi: Displaying Unicode emoji \xF0\x9F\x99\x8A  from SQL chat database in TMemo

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8, emoji, vcl

I get strings with Unicode emojis like

```
$F09F998A
```

or

```
$F0 $9F $99 $8A
```

or

```
\xF0\x9F\x99\x8A
```

->  from an SQL database.

```
s1 := '$F09F998A'; // From Database
s2 := '$F0 $9F $99 $8A'; // From Database
s3 := '\xF0\x9F\x99\x8A'; // From Database
```

How do I convert s1,s2,s3 to display as  in e.g., a `TMemo` element?

How do I convert s1,s2 or s3?

```
// Memo1.lines.add('how to convert ' + ????? -> $F0 $9F $99 $8A );

Memo1.lines.add('how to convert ' + s1 + s2 + c3 + ' as Emoji?');
```

I want convert < s := '\xF0\x9F\x99\x8A'; > to add to a Memo field to show as Emoji.

```
function convert_as_Emoji(s: string):string;
begin
  result := ???
end;
```

and then

```
var s : string;

s := '\xF0\x9F\x99\x8A'; 

Memo1.lines.add(convert_as_Emoji(s));
```

Comment: How do you access the database? Usually you can already define a character set you want to use in the connection to the database. If that is the case, then specify that you want to use UTF-8 as client character set.

Comment: Your hex codes are not the same!

Comment: In UTF-8,  is bytes `$F0 $9F $99 $8A`

Comment: Also, do you use VCL or FMX?

Comment: Why the UTF-32 tag? Your emoji is (as per 3rd example) UTF-8 and you want to convert that into [UTF-16 LE for the WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66072117/4299358). Also "_SQL Chat Database_" can mean anything - which DBMS has been used (f.e. MySQL or SQLite or Oracle...)?

Comment: I use VCL Forms

Comment: `"I get strings with Unicode emojis"` - please be more specific: how do you get the strings, in which dataype are they stored in?

Comment: @mjn: as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I do this with success:

> > In UTF-8,  is bytes $F0 $9F $99 $8A – Remy Lebeau

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bytes: array[0..3] of byte;
  str: string;
const emoji = '$F0$9F$99$8A';  //  
begin
  bytes[0] := strtoint('$F0'); // bytes[0] := $F0;
  bytes[1] := strtoint('$9F'); // bytes[1] := $9F;
  bytes[2] := strtoint('$99'); // bytes[2] := $99;
  bytes[3] := strtoint('$8A'); // bytes[3] := $8A;

  str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
  showmessage(str);
end;
```

Comment: But as per your ambiguous descriptions this is not "_converting_" from `'\xF0\x9F\x99\x8A'` because the latter is a String with leading backslashes and the character `x`, and so is `'$F0 $9F $99 $8A'` nowhere converted, too. Where's your routine to extract the values from the String to turn into separate Bytes? You're not even **converting** from `$F09F998A`. Do you even know you can make a String out of `#$F0#$9F#$99#$8A`?

Comment: @AmigoJack: -> Where's your routine to extract the values from the String. -> you can write the basic routine yourself -> try splitstring;

Comment: This version of your "answer" is even worse than the first - every sane person would actually make use of the `emoji` constant and use [`Ord()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Ord) from start to end of a String per character. I wasn't asking about how to split Strings - I was showing up how improperly you formulated question (needing 6 edits), comments and answer. That's why users want blacklists: to never help those again who keep half of everything in their head to later surprise everyone with a "correct" "solution".

Comment: @AmigoJack: can you anything say to the question : Displaying Unicode emoji \xF0\x9F\x99\x8A  from SQL chat database in TMemo -> try the Button1Click code from my answer