# how to treat special characters with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, sendgrid, sendmail

I have a function using postgresql (plpgsql) that sends emails using the sendgrid api, the content of this email is a .csv file, containing product names, etc.

the email is sent successfully, the process goes very well, but special characters are handled in an unexpected way
for example, I have a product called:

ÓLEO DIESEL

in my .csv file it is seen as:

Ã“LEO DIESEL B S10

the problem is with the special characters.

I did a test by opening my .csv file in my notepad++, I converted the file to utf-8-bom, reopened it in my excel and the special characters were being listed correctly, my question is: how can I convert the file for utf-8-good? or if anyone has a better way to handle special characters and wants to introduce me, I would be welcome.

my function:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_email_cotacao(premetente json, pdestinatario json, prespostapara json, passunto text, pconteudo json, pdatacotacao date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, pidempresa integer[] DEFAULT ARRAY[0])
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
DECLARE
    VVariavelGenerica                   RECORD;
BEGIN
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(vc.id_empresa) 
    INTO pidempresa
    FROM vw vc
    WHERE vc.registro_ativo;

    WITH sub_arquivos AS (
        WITH sub_arquivo AS (
            SELECT 
                CONCAT(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MI'), '.csv') nome_arquivo,
                 TRANSLATE(ENCODE(CONVERT_TO(
                    CONCAT(E'Data Cotacao;Fornecedor;Produto;Empresa;Tipo Frete;Preco;Frete;Valor Unitario\n'
                        , ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(
                            CONCAT_WS(';' 
                                    , TO_CHAR(vc.data_cotacao, 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                                    , TRIM(vc.fornecedor)
                                    , vc.produto 
                                    , vc.empresa 
                                    , vc.tipo_frete 
                                    , TRIM(vc.preco_unitario)
                                    , vc.valor_frete
                                    , vc.valor_unitario
                            )
                        ), E'\n')
                    ), 'UTF8'), 'base64'), E'\n', '') conteudo_arquivo  
            FROM vw_cotacao vc
            WHERE vc.data_cotacao = PDataCotacao
            AND (vc.id_empresa = ANY(PIdEmpresa) OR PIdEmpresa[1] = 0)
        )
        SELECT
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'type', 'text/plain'
                , 'filename', sub.nome_arquivo 
                , 'content',  sub.conteudo_arquivo
                , 'disposition', 'attachment'
            ) arquivo_json
        FROM    sub_arquivo sub
    ), sub_email AS (
        SELECT  
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'Authorization', 'my-token'
                , 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
            ) headers
            , JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'from', PRemetente
                , 'personalizations', JSON_BUILD_ARRAY(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('to', PDestinatario))
                , 'reply_to', PRespostaPara
                -- reply_to_list, JSON_BUILD_ARRAY(PRespostaPara)
                , 'subject', PAssunto
                , 'content', PConteudo
                , 'attachments', JSON_AGG(sub.arquivo_json)
                , 'tracking_settings', 
                    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                        '', JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('enable', TRUE, '', TRUE)
                        , 'open_tracking', JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('', TRUE, 'substitution_tag', '%open-%')
                        , '', JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('', TRUE)
                    )
            ) body
        FROM    sub_arquivos sub
    )
    SELECT  *
    INTO    VVariavelGenerica
    FROM    sub_email sub, f_request_http(
            'POST', -- metodo 
            '', -- url 
            CAST(sub.headers AS TEXT),
            CAST(sub.body AS TEXT)
        );
        
    RAISE NOTICE '%', VVariavelGenerica;
END;
  $function$
;

SELECT * FROM public.f_email_cotacao(
        JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('email', '..', ', '.. ') 
        , JSON_BUILD_ARRAY(
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('', '...', ' ')
                ) 
        , CAST(CONCAT('..', .., 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS TEXT)
        , JSON_BUILD_ARRAY(
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'type', 'text/plain'
                , 'value', '..'
            ) 
        ) -- content
);
```

Comment: Does Excel read the file correctly if you encode it with UTF-16?

Comment: Hi, I saved the file as: UTF-16 BE
and it worked, but my data quotation header came with this extra word: þÿ
ending up like this: þÿQuote Date @AndrewMorton

Comment: Can you try UTF-16LE ? Slightly related: [Why does Windows use UTF-16LE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66072117/why-does-windows-use-utf-16le)

Comment: I did what you asked, and the result was successful. There was only one problem, my file lost the columns it had (date in column A, supplier in column B, etc.), it is a customer requirement.
 And started to present everything in a single column @AndrewMorton

Comment: Have you tried E'' notation ?

Comment: @GuilhermeRodrigues Is adding the BOM to the UTF-8 version a possibility?

Comment: Actually, this looks like an encoding issue. Initially, when you are creating a database you have to define encoding usually default option is UTF-8. which won't be possible to alter this...  The only way to change encoding is drop and recreate database with different encoding..

CREATE DATABASE your_database_name with encoding 'latin1';

Comment: puts, it went bad :c @hackwithharsha

Comment: It looks like the file is correct UTF-8, but you view it with something that does not expect UTF-8. For an exact answer, you have to tell us which bytes end up in the CSV file.

Comment: this really seems to be an Excel and/or windows problem. stemming from Microsofts reluctant policy on utf8